# About swift Parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have a question.I'm trying to parse JSON.However,I got a error. It's called "Cannot call value of non-function type '[Movie]' "  in  this line "completionHandler(modelList)" Can you help me please?

This my class;

```
class Movie {
    var type : String?
    var title: String?
    var thumbnail: String?
    var id: String?

    init(Dictionary : [String:AnyObject]){
        self.title = Dictionary["Title"] as? String
        self.id = Dictionary["Id"] as? String
        self.type = Dictionary["Type"] as? String   
    }
    static func fetchData(completionHandler: ([Movie])) -> () {
        let urlString = "http://tcm-api.azurewebsites.net/api/movie/search?term='Batman'&page=1"
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            do {
                var modelList = [Movie]()

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)
                for resultDictionary in json["Data"]!!["Results"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]  {
                    let model  = Movie(Dictionary: resultDictionary)
                    modelList.append(model)
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(modelList)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your function declaration:

```
func fetchData(completionHandler:([Movie]))->() {
```

which is equal to:

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: [Movie]) {
```

What you want is this:

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: [Movie] -> Void) {
```